# Custom Fonts doesn't work in flutter when used in modules

Tags: flutter, dart

i have project structured like this:

```
--
  --app
  --core
  --module
```

**core:** a flutter package that contains assets

**app:** a flutter application that depands on core

**module:** a flutter module that depands on core

in my ThemeData I used `packages/core/MyCustomFont` in fontFamily parameters ( and TextStyles ). it works in app but when i build the module and use it in a native android application it shows the default font.

I unzip the android app with modules's apk and the fonts are there ( in `assets/flutter_assets` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duplicating the assets in module solved the problem.
also must refrence fontFamily without prefix like `MyCustomFont` and not `packages/core/MyCustomFont`

i will try to find a better answer and update this answer.

Comment: Hi, did you find another way to solve this issue? We're facing the same issue when embedding a module into an android app

Comment: @Gmeister4 Unfortunately not yet

Comment: still a no @Sahandevs ? without duplicating assets ?